# Moving Nodes of XML to separate new Node using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am completely new to XSLT 
My Input XML as fallows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
   <system>Amisys</system>
   <FindReceiptDetailARRequest>
      <LegacySystem>Amisys</LegacySystem>
      <LegacyUserID>ratna</LegacyUserID>
      <LegacyPassword>ratna</LegacyPassword>
      <OtherLogin />
      <OtherPassword />
      <AddSecurLogin />
      <AddSecurPassword />
      <businessArea>PQAA</businessArea>
      <GroupNumber>KISHG2D2</GroupNumber>
      <receiptNumber>OKEY00000698</receiptNumber>
      <billTo>INDIVIDUAL</billTo>
      <accountId>CR1277C01</accountId>
      <GroupId>KISHG2</GroupId>
      <METHOD>POST</METHOD>
      <eao>08212015</eao>
   </FindReceiptDetailARRequest>
   <results>
      <ver:receiptDetailHistoryRS xmlns:ver="version4">
         <transactionSuccess>true</transactionSuccess>
         <accountName>NEW CONTRACT TIMEI</accountName>
         <ver:receiptDetails>
            <ver:receiptDetail>
               <appliedAmount>0</appliedAmount>
               <divisionNumber>127776DIV3</divisionNumber>
               <invoiceNumber />
               <month>2015/02</month>
               <processedDate>2015-07-28T00:00:00-04:00</processedDate>
               <receiptNumber>OKEY00000699</receiptNumber>
               <unappliedAmount>187.00</unappliedAmount>
            </ver:receiptDetail>
            <ver:receiptDetail>
               <appliedAmount>190.00</appliedAmount>
               <divisionNumber>127776DIV3</divisionNumber>
               <invoiceNumber />
               <month>2015/02</month>
               <processedDate>2015-07-28T00:00:00-04:00</processedDate>
               <receiptNumber>OKEY00000698</receiptNumber>
               <unappliedAmount>0</unappliedAmount>
            </ver:receiptDetail>
         </ver:receiptDetails>
         <receiptDetailHistorySC>
            <accountId>CR1277C01</accountId>
            <billTo>INDIVIDUAL</billTo>
            <divisionNumber />
            <invoiceNumber />
            <receiptNumber />
         </receiptDetailHistorySC>
      </ver:receiptDetailHistoryRS>
   </results>
</response>
```

I want move all the nodes under `<ver:receiptDetails>` to separate new node `<prvAssocList>`.

My result XML should look like as fallows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FindReceiptDetailScreenResults>
   <prvAssocList>
      <prvAssocInfo>
         <prvAssocCode>OKEY00000699</prvAssocCode>
      </prvAssocInfo>
      <prvAssocInfo>
         <prvAssocCode>OKEY00000698</prvAssocCode>
      </prvAssocInfo>
   </prvAssocList>
</FindReceiptDetailScreenResults>
```

I am trying with fallowing XSLT but not working for me. Could you help on this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:variable name="SYS" select="//system" />
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <FindReceiptDetailScreenResults>
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="Fault">
               <xsl:apply-templates select="Fault" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="//results" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
      </FindReceiptDetailScreenResults>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="Fault">
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="faultactor = 'Amisys'">
            <PQMessage>not found</PQMessage>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <PQMessage>
               <xsl:value-of select="faultstring" />
            </PQMessage>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="//results">
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="$SYS = 'Amisys'">
            <xsl:if test="PQMessage[string(.)]">
               <PQMessage>
                  <xsl:value-of select="PQMessage[string(.)]" />
               </PQMessage>
            </xsl:if>
            <prvAssocList>
               <xsl:for-each select="/response/results/ver:receiptDetailHistoryRS/ver:receiptDetails/ver:receiptDetail[1]">
                  <prvAssocInfo>
                     <prvAssocCode>
                        <xsl:value-of select="receiptNumber" />
                     </prvAssocCode>
                  </prvAssocInfo>
               </xsl:for-each>
            </prvAssocList>
         </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your description of the problem doesn't go well with the expected transformation. Can you try restating the problem.

Comment: Need proper XSLT to get out put XML from the given input XML

Comment: How to write XSLT to get the below output XML from the given input XML.    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FindReceiptDetailScreenResults>
   <prvAssocList>
      <prvAssocInfo>
         <prvAssocCode>OKEY00000699</prvAssocCode>
      </prvAssocInfo>
      <prvAssocInfo>
         <prvAssocCode>OKEY00000698</prvAssocCode>
      </prvAssocInfo>
   </prvAssocList>
</FindReceiptDetailScreenResults>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "not working", are you actually getting an error?

The problem is with this line:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/response/results/ver:receiptDetailHistoryRS/ver:receiptDetails/ver:receiptDetail[1]">
```

You have not declared the namespace prefix `ver` in your XSLT, so I would expect the XSLT to fail with an error `Undeclared namespace prefix {ver}`. Just because the namespace prefix is declared as `ver` in the XML, you still need to declare it in your XSLT too if you want to access the nodes in the XML.

So, the first thing you need to do is declare the namespace prefix in your XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:ver="version4">
```

The next problem is you have put `[1]` at the end of the expression. This means the expression will get only the first `receiptDetail` element (or rather, it will get the first `receiptDetail` under each `receiptDetails` node, should there be multiple `receiptDetails` node).

Try this XSLT (I've removed the check on `fault` just to simplify things)

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:ver="version4" exclude-result-prefixes="ver">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
   <xsl:variable name="SYS" select="//system" />
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <FindReceiptDetailScreenResults>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="//results" />
      </FindReceiptDetailScreenResults>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="results">
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="$SYS = 'Amisys'">
            <prvAssocList>
               <xsl:for-each select="/response/results/ver:receiptDetailHistoryRS/ver:receiptDetails/ver:receiptDetail[1]">
                  <prvAssocInfo>
                     <prvAssocCode>
                        <xsl:value-of select="receiptNumber" />
                     </prvAssocCode>
                  </prvAssocInfo>
               </xsl:for-each>
            </prvAssocList>
         </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Working now, Thanks a lot.